Buck converter voltage inverter power glitch
I'm using a standard buck converter based on lm2596 to convert 15V to -12V (this is done by connecting 15V to IN+, GND to OUT+ and the -12V should now be OUT-).
When doing this if the input voltage raises too slowly (in my case using a bench power supply, with time taken to rise on the order of milliseconds) the buck converter keeps the voltage down at 2 to 3 volts and drains all the amps that the power supply can give it.
My power supply can supply up to 10 amperes of current.
This doesn't happen when the voltage rises quickly (for example by having the power supply already on and touching the metal contacts).
I know that the lm2596 has a on/off pin but I was trying to find a solution that doesn't involve re-soldering it.
What could be the issue here?

Please include a diagram and a picture of your setup.

What is the maximum current your power supply can deliver? You didn't give us enough details to help you out. Please include as much detail as you can, including drawings, schematics, diagrams, pictures, specifications of your power supply.

What do you mean by "the buck converter keeps the voltage to 2/3 volts"? Two thirds of the supply voltage (10 volts) or two thirds of 1 volt?

I mean something like 3 volts, last time I checked it was 4 volts with like 1 max amp

Oh, you meant to say "2-3" (2 to 3) volts. Thank you.

On page 14 of the LM2596 datasheet (https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2596.pdf) is a hint to the possible cause of your problem:

This type of inverting regulator can require relatively large amounts of input current when starting up, even with
light loads. Input currents as high as the LM2596 current limit (approximately 4.5 A) are required for at least 2 ms
or more, until the output reaches its nominal output voltage. The actual time depends on the output voltage and
the size of the output capacitor. Input power sources that are current limited or sources that can not deliver these
currents without getting loaded down, can not work correctly.

On page 11 of this datasheet, it is mentioned:

This delayed start-up feature is useful in situations where the input power source is limited in the amount of
current it can deliver. It allows the input voltage to rise to a higher voltage before the regulator starts operating.
Buck regulators require less input current at higher input voltages.

I have emphasized the part which tells you why your converter draws so much current at startup: PWM converters draw more current at lower input voltages, and less current at higher input voltages, which is why you have such a large current draw at low voltages.
So you would need to add the recommended start-up delay or undervoltage lockout circuit to the enable pin to allow the input voltage to fully rise before LM2596 starts running.

Pay attention to the diode D3 in the inverting circuit: it should be there to prevent unwanted voltage overshoot, as explained on page  13:

Without diode D3, when the input voltage is first applied, the charging current of CIN can pull the output positive
by several volts for a short period of time. Adding D3 prevents the output from going positive by more than a
diode voltage.

As usual, many problems can be traced and solved by reading datasheets carefully, but most of us don't do that. 

Evidently I hadn't read the datasheet well enough, thanks

@Sonic803 You're welcome. We all do that from time to time. So, what is the maximum amperage of your power supply? Also, if my answer has helped solve your problem, please mark it as "Accepted answer", so that it shows your question as "Solved" on the list of posed questions on StackExchange. Thank you.

I dont't think the issue was the maximum amperage but the fact that it raised the voltage slowly (I had the maximum set to 10 amp). I hope that using the rc circuit on the on/off pin solves the issue

@Sonic803 It could be that your power supply is sensitive to fast current transients and that your LM2596 circuit has an input capacitor sufficiently large to trigger it in combination with the 4.5 amps being drawn by the IC . I have had occasional strange behavior from my power supplies due to sudden changes in loads, and it was sometimes hard to pinpoint the exact "mechanism" of why and how it was happening.

Adding the rc circuit still doesn't solve the issue with the bench power supply, while it still works with a laptop power supply. Maybe using the bjt configuration they list in the documentation could solve it, but if the problem rises only with the bench power supply I don't really care

@Sonic803 It could be that your RC time constant is too short and the voltage doesn't get to rise high enough before the regulator starts drawing power. The schematic uses 0.1 uF, you could try anything from 0.22 uF to 2.2 uF until it works. Finally, the Zener-transistor circuit would definitely allow the voltage to get high enough before the regulator starts drawing current, just make sure the set value is the right one (experimentally).

I actually used a 4.7 uF capacitor and 2 68kOhm resistors, so I dont think that is the issue. Maybe in the future I will try the zener circuit.
